# How to cache component dom and state and render it base on my logic?

Tags: vue.js

In my page I have component. the component is rendered and alive possibly have changes (like someone type in input and etc.).

How in vue I cache this component and their state and render it again base on my logic and still keep the binding and everything?

I want to do something similar to vue keep-alive, take a snapshot of component (maybe include the dom) and store it in variable (snapshot).

according to some logic I do, I want to re-render or just render it again. (I prefer not to keep it on the dom, maybe in memory).

What is the vue way to do this?

I think something like my pseudo code this might help:

```
 const compRef = this.$ref.comp;
 const compInMemory = takeSnapshot(compRef);

 ..
 if (someLogic) {
   renderComponent(compInMemroy)
 }
```

Comment: If a component appearance depends on its state then you should just save its state and restore it in order to render the component as it was rendered before making snapshot. So you should design your component to look the same if it has the same state.

Comment: @Jon Sud, I am not that sure regarding this but why not to use v-show to hide/show the component. This way you would be able to preserve the state and not have to worry about taking component's snapshot and adding it to DOM again. Or is it necessary to manually add and remove the component from DOM?